# quoted parameters to golang sqlc

Tags: go, sqlc

using sqlc to generate db methods.
Have below query

```sql
-- name: RemoveRows:exec
DELETE FROM demotable
WHERE last_updated < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' SECOND);
```

I want to pass `30` as parameter but I used below query, then quotes are not coming and db giving error.

```sql
-- name: RemoveRows:exec
DELETE FROM demotable
WHERE last_updated < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL $1 SECOND);
```

Tried quoting `$1` but sqlc thinking it is string

```sql
-- name: RemoveRows:exec
DELETE FROM demotable
WHERE last_updated < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '$1' SECOND);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or rather than mucking around trying to trick the type system just do

```
... - ($1 * interval '1 minute')
```